# How to make NSSortDescriptor to sort by count of entity relationship (xcode)?

Tags: xcode, iphone-4, nssortdescriptor

ok.. simple example like that

firstEntity has a relationship called "Relation" to secondEntity, it is one to many relationship.

I want to fetch all object of firstEntity but with sort by count of Relation

example

```
fE1 has 1 relation to sE1
fE2 has 3 relation to sE2,sE3 and sE4
fE3 has 2 relation to sE5 and sE6
```

so the result will

```
fE1 has 1 relation to sE1
fE3 has 2 relation to sE5 and sE6
fE2 has 3 relation to sE2,sE3 and sE4
```

the problem like this.. how to make sortDescriptor correctly?

====================

this another example:

```
NSString * sort=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Business.@count"];
```

Business is Relation

from table Tag to table Biz

it's mean that biz have a Tag relation but Tag have many biz relation

is it like that to make that sortString?